# Insert parameters into laravel method

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5.3

I want to insert two parameters into a method called creaChecklist() that is into the method store() but there are not recognized.

Method one:

```
    public function creaChecklist($subcategoriaID, $richiesta_id){

    $processo_id = \App\SubCategoria::find((int)$subcategoriaID)->processo_id;

    $fasiprocesso = DB::table('fasi_processo')->where('processo_id',$processo_id)->get();

    foreach($fasiprocesso as $faseprocesso){
        DB::table('checklists')->insert(
            [
                'richiesta_id' => $richiesta_id,
                'nome' => $faseprocesso->nome,
                'descrizione' => $faseprocesso->descrizione,
                'posizione' => $faseprocesso->posizione,
                'isCheck' => 0,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Method two:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'categoria'=>'required',
        'subcategoria'=>'required',
        'oggetto'=>'required'
    ],
    [
        'categoria.required'=>'La categoria é obbligatoria',
        'subcategoria.required'=>'La sotto categoria é obbligatoria',
        'oggetto.required'=>'L\'oggetto é obbligatorio'
    ]);


    $richiesta = new \App\Richiesta();

    $richiesta->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $richiesta->nome = Auth::user()->nome;
    $richiesta->cognome = Auth::user()->cognome;
    $richiesta->categoria = $request->input('categoria');
    $richiesta->subcategoria = $request->input('subcategoria');
    $richiesta->oggetto = $request->input('oggetto');

    $richiesta->save();

    $richiesta_id = $richiesta->id;
    $subcategoriaID = $request->get('subcategoria');

    $this->creaChecklist($subcategoriaID,$richiesta_id);

    return redirect('/le_mie_richieste');
}
```

IMPORTANT:
I used dd() and i see that the parameters are there! If i put static int parameter all methods work.

SOLUTION:
To allow the parameter to be accepted, it must be casted to int.

```
$subcategoriaID = (int)$request->get('subcategoria');
```

Comment: You should post your code here as text, not as images.

Comment: You should put the code as text-based code in your question instead of linking to external images, for more helpful responses.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Are you saying it works when you cast the arguments  as integers? that makes sense.

Comment: @CUGreen When i insert manually a value integer work good. But i need to insert dinamic parameters.

Comment: are you getting those two arguments in `creaChecklist` method?

Comment: Try casting to int before calling the method

Comment: Okey thank you everyone, i find the problem. I must casting the value request to int! Solution is over.